# Change JFrame in WindowBuilder Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, jframe

I'm working with swing and I'm not able to change the JFrame in COMPONENTS area in WindowBuilder.
I can only see the main frame.
When I press a button I create a new Frame but I cant edit it with WindowBuilder.

[image]

```
        frameMain.setVisible(false);
        frameLogin = new JFrame("Login Admin");
        frameLogin.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frameLogin.setSize(600, 400);
        frameLogin.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frameLogin.setVisible(true);
```

**I WANT TO EDIT frameLogin in WindowBuilder, any solution?**
By creating a new JFrame in WindowBuilder it creates another class in other file.
[image]

Comment: Your `frameLogin` is of type `JFrame`, you cannot edit the standard library. Create a new `JFrame` using the WindowBuilder and use that in your code.

Comment: @kalsowerus Look I edit the post. Anyway it creates me in another file the frame. I want it in the same file, is the possibile?

Comment: Any good reason why you need that? Multiple classes in the same file are rarely a good idea.

Comment: I'm creating an mvc java app so I want just to have 3 classes + 1 (main)... I can't have more files... @kalsowerus

Comment: In MVC you have 3 classes per View. I think you should look at your FrameLogin as another View with it's own controller and model. Otherwise I don't know enough about WindowBuilder to help you.

Comment: Ok thank you. I proceed in this way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did this :
In my view (frameMain) I declared this :

```
private loginFrameAdmin frameLoginA;
private loginFrameUser frameLoginU;
```

where loginFrameAdmin is a JFrame like this :

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class loginFrameAdmin {

    private JFrame frameLogin;
    public loginFrameAdmin() {
        frameLogin = new JFrame("Login Amministratore");
        frameLogin.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frameLogin.setSize(600, 400);
        frameLogin.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frameLogin.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Then in the same view (frameMain) I added a class :

```
public void adminPage() {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Login for admins");
        frameMain.setVisible(false);
        frameLoginA = new loginFrameAdmin();
    }
```

And now I'm able to edit my JFrame, thanks to @kalsowerus